# Smarty - transfer simple code to smarty

Tags: smarty

I have this simple code and I need help with transfer to smarty. What will be the template? What will be the file?

```
  <?php
  if($_POST){
  $maxCislo = $_POST["maxCislo"];
  if($maxCislo >= 2;) {
  echo "2; "

    }
 for($i = 3; $i < $maxCislo; $i = $i + 2){
 $l = 0;
for($j = 2; $i > $j; $j++) {
if($i % $j == 0){
$l++;
 }
 }
if($l == 0){
echo "$i; ";
 }
}
 }
  ?>
 <html>
 <form method="post" action="#">
 <input type="text" name="maxCislo">
 <input type="submit" value="Odeslat">
 </form>
 </html>
```

We are here to do it 5 hours and somehow I still can not. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is, or what your code actually does, but it looks like it would be fairly simple to convert to Smarty just by replacing each line of PHP with the Smarty equivalent.

Here are some hints:

- for `if` statements, use `{if}...{/if}`: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl
- for `$_POST['foo']`, use `$smarty.post.foo`: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#language.variables.smarty.request
- for assigning one variable to another, use `{assign var=name value=$value}`: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl
- math(s) like `$i % $j` can be output directly: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.math.tpl
- ... or used in the value of an `{assign}` or other function by using double quotes and backticks: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.quotes.tpl
- a `for` loop can be implemented using `{section}`: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.section.tpl

Comment: @Atjak If you want somebody to write your code for you, I suggest you pay a professional programmer. If you have specific questions or problems, ask here and somebody may be kind enough to help you for free.